# After enabling full screen through f11 disable full screen through javascript

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser

By pressing below button i am able to enable and disable fullscreenmode but after f12 is pressed i am not enable to disable fullscreen mode.I refered other answers they have gave only a ways to detect whether window is in full screen mode or not .I am not able to get code for disabling full screen mode from fullscreen(made through f11 key).I tried by triggering f11 through code but it didnt work.Is there any solution for it in all the browsers?

```
 Html code:
     <button id="fullbutton" width="60px" height="60px" alt="logo" onclick="toggleFullScreen(this)">On</button>

Javascript code :

function toggleFullScreen(element) {
//first part 

if((window.fullScreen) || (window.outerWidth === screen.width && window.outerHeight == screen.height)) {

console.log("full screen is enabled ")

if (document.exitFullscreen)
    document.exitFullscreen();
else if (document.msExitFullscreen)
    document.msExitFullscreen();
else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen)
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen)
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();


}else {

//second part


if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {


if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
  document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
} else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
  document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  //for mozilla
} else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {      

 document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen
      (Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);   //for chrome
     }  else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
    document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
}//for ie

        //   document.getElementById('fullbutton').innerText = 'Off';

   } else {  

    // document.getElementById('fullbutton').innerText = 'On';
    if (document.msFullscreenElement) {
    document.msExitFullscreen();
    } //for ie
   if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
     document.cancelFullScreen();  
    }   
  else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();   //for mozilla
   } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
   }//for chrome

    }



  console.log("full screen is not enabled ")

   }

   }
```

Also after enabling through f11 if i give `document.webkitIsFullScreen` result is giving false .I tried by giving `document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen()` and then `document.webkitCancelFullScreen()` that too didnt work.

Comment: so, you're only having an issue with webkit browsers (like Chrome)?

Comment: ya @JaromandaX. Also i want solutions in mozilla and ie

Comment: @JaromandaX nope. Once again,  this API's implementation is an hell of a mess.. Gecko did camelCase fullScreen, only them did...

Comment: Sorry, MDN documentation is wrong!! (which is a first!) @Kaiido - I should not argue with you :p

Comment: Oh I've got things wrong quite often, and it's normal to get lost in *webkit-ms-o-moz-f[s||S]* ApI (specs require fs, but I fear there still needs some time before we've got it unprefixed everywhere...)

Comment: @Ajith have you found any solution?

Comment: @ChrisP no i was not able to find a way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>F11</kbd> fullscreen mode is a browser/OS feature that you don't have access to from javascript, just like you don't have access to how the address bar is displayed.

What you can control is the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), and this is what the `document.exitFullscreen`, or `document.fullscreenElement` are based on.

But this fullscreen API is not the same as the <kbd>F11</kbd> one.

---

Ps: actually, there is the [`display-mode` media-query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode) which should let us know about it.
But it seems that only FireFox did implement it as of now.

```js
const query = matchMedia("all and (display-mode: fullscreen");
query.onchange = e => {
  console.log(query.matches ? 'entered' : 'exited', 'fullscreen mode');
};
```

```html
<p>From Firefox, try to enter or exit FullScreen mode</p>
```

Comment: So your answer is it is not possible to make this functionality ?

Comment: @Ajith that's about it. But if it is important for you, just force the use of the JS API, this way you'll have the control. (There might be ways to make guesses about it by looking at the `window.screen` object, but nothing too stable is available no..)

Comment: ok thanks .i thought using this method now when full screen is created through  f11  and users are pressing button i am going to create a notification(popup) and tell  "press f11 to disable full screen"  @kaiido

Comment: Unfortunately, F11 is not an universal key for this mode. On osX, it's "cmd + shift + F" or even just click on the expand button of the app's top-bar and on every OS I guess there is a "View > Enter Full Screen", hard to catch....

Comment: the media query works in Chromium based browsers now as well