# Exit fullscreen not working on chrome? [What I'm missing?]

Tags: javascript, html5-fullscreen

I have two buttons on my screen. each one fires a piece of javascript code to enter and exit fullscreen mode.

**Button 1:** Enter Fullscreen Mode

**Button 2:** Exit Fullscreen Mode

If I first click on **Button 1** it brings me to fullscreen mode and then if I click on **Button 2** it'll exit fullscreen mode.

BUT if I enter fullscreen mode using **F11** or via **chrome menu**, unexpectedly **Button 2** doesn't work anymore.

Why this happens and how to fix it?

Button 1 code :

```
goFullscreen();
function goFullscreen() {
    var el = document.documentElement,
      rfs = el.requestFullscreen
        || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
        || el.mozRequestFullScreen
        || el.msRequestFullscreen 
    ;

    rfs.call(el);
}
```

Button 2 code :

```
document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
```

I've tried this with no luck too:

```
document.webkitExitFullscreen();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exit fullscreen onclick using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672561/how-to-exit-fullscreen-onclick-using-javascript)

Comment: Try document.webkitExitFullscreen(); instead of document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672683/6358346

Comment: I'm sorry but document.webkitExitFullscreen(); doesn't work too, I'm totally confused :(

Comment: The link just recommended to use document.webkitExitFullscreen(); Am I right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After enabling full screen through f11 disable full screen through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128490)

Comment: So according to this link, it is not possible to make this functionality on chrome?

Comment: Thanks everyone you saved a lot of time for me ...:)

Comment: @SaraRee There is also `document.webkitCancelFullScreen` however you missed a *critical* clarification here: are you trying to detect the event when the user has exited fullscreen or are trying to give them an anchor or button to press that exits fullscreen? That is absolutely critical for you to get the correct answer.

Comment: @SaraRee Also try the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25876513/606371

Answer (score 2):

You should validate before executing....

```js
    function FullScreen(divID) {
        fnFullScreen(divID, !IsFullScreen());
    }
    function IsFullScreen() {
        return (document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement !== null) ||
                 (document.webkitFullscreenElement && document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null) ||
                 (document.mozFullScreenElement && document.mozFullScreenElement !== null) ||
                 (document.msFullscreenElement && document.msFullscreenElement !== null);
    }
    function fnFullScreen(divID, TurnOn) { 
        if (TurnOn) {
            var docElm = $('#' + divID).parent()[0];
            if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
                docElm.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (docElm.msRequestFullscreen) {
                docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
            $('#' + divID).css("min-height", "100vh");
            $('.btnFullScreen').html('Exit Full Screen');
        } else { 
            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                document.exitFullscreen().catch(() => { });
            } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
                document.webkitExitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                document.msExitFullscreen();
            }
             
            $('#' + divID).css("min-height", "");
            $('.btnFullScreen').html('Full Screen');
        }
    }
```

```html
 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="body">
   <div id="div1"> <button class="btnFullScreen"  onclick="FullScreen('div1')">Full Screen</button> click to full screen</div>
   </div>
```